# Reducing spanning vector elements to {1, 0, -1}

Tags: linear-algebra, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

**Background** 
I'm working on a project that involves computing the homology of simplicial complexes. The way this is done results in the spanning set of vectors that describes the set of homology groups or holes in the complex, and these vectors are typically floating point due to how they are calculated. However, I care about linear combinations of these vectors that consist of values -1, 0, and 1 because these values correspond to discrete simplices that make up each hole.

**Problem** 
Essentially, I have a set of vectors with floating point values that I want to simplify to an equivalent spanning set where the vectors only contain elements -1, 0, and 1. I know that all sets I will be applying this method to can be expressed this way.

**Attempts** 
Currently, I have the following algorithm, which basically does row operations on a matrix with rows consisting of the spanning vectors.

```
def simplify(a, tol=1e-5) -> np.matrix:    
    r = a.copy()

    for i in range(r.shape[0]):
        for e, p in enumerate(r[i]):
            if not is_unit(p):
                r[i] = r[i] / p
                for j in it.chain(range(0, i), range(i+1, r.shape[0])):
                    r[j] -= r[j, e] * r[i]

    return as_unit(r, tol=tol)
```

Note that `is_unit` and `to_unit` check proximity to and round to the nearest whole number given the tolerance. While this works for small cases, it fails in specific instances related to the homology code (if you're familiar with it, it fails to simplify when there are simplices of dimension $n+1$).

If I start with the following vectors (each vector is a row of this matrix, so in this case, we have 2 6-vectors):

$ \begin{bmatrix} 
0.21968405 & 0.08418094 & -0.69191091 & 0.38804592 & 0.30386499 & -0.47222686 \\
0.67211526 & -0.39947495 & -0.14580566 & -0.12683464 &  0.27264031 & 0.52630959 
\end{bmatrix}$

This yields:

$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 2 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
-3 & 1 & 3 & -1 & -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Even though it could be described as:

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. In dimension 2, any two linearly independent vectors will span the whole space.

Comment: We're meant to interpret your example as two 6-vectors, not six 2-vectors, right?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'm trying to represent the first floating floating point column vectors as a column vectors consisting of -1, 0, and 1.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah, that's correct. I'll edit and make a comment about that!

Comment: I don't see how $(1,-1,-1,-1,0,0)$ could be a linear combination of $(-1,0,2,-1,-1,1)$ and $(-3,1,3,-1,-2,0)$.

Comment: @noahbkim: why would you assume that's possible?

Comment: To preface this, I'm not deeply familiar with the subject. But what I understand is that each element of the vector corresponds to a traversal of a simplex in the boundary. With a hole in a triangle between points x, y, and z, the homology groups of dimensions 1 would consist of one vector with $[1, 1, 1]^T$ as in $[xy, yz, zx]$. Since these holes will be in the spanning set, I believe it's possible to go from one form to the other. @MartinArgerami

Comment: @GerryMyerson hmm, it's possible my method is wrong. Or, I'm not thinking about this correctly in the first place! That would certainly explain why it seems impossible to get to the former version, but I'll have to go back to the drawing board. Edit: I guess what I'm assuming in my method is that doing row operations on the vectors preserves the spanning set, and I'm not sure if this is the case off the top of my head.

Comment: @noahbkim: note that row operations will preserve the **dimension** of the column space, but not the column space itself.

Comment: @MartinArgerami let me edit the question format to make sure I'm correctly explaining what I mean by row operations; I'm first transposing the column vectors.

Comment: Still what you are saying does not hold. Now you are claiming that the span of the two vectors with lots of decimals agree with the span of $(-1,0,2,-1,-1,1)$ and $(-3,1,3,-1,-2,0)$. Not true. If you try to write $$\begin{bmatrix} 
0.21968405 & 0.08418094 & -0.69191091 & 0.38804592 & 0.30386499 & -0.47222686  
\end{bmatrix}$$ as $\alpha(-1,0,2,-1,-1,1)+\beta(-3,1,3,-1,-2,0)$, you immediately get from the second coordinate that $\beta= 0.08418094$, and from the six that $\alpha= -0.47222686$. But in the fourth, $-\alpha-\beta\ne0.38804592$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: that makes sense. Does this mean that doing row operations on the matrix of row vectors does not preserve the span? And if so, can you think of any other way to manipulate the spanning set besides brute forcing combinations until I get the form I'm hoping for? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, so it looks like your algorithm has some issues with ordering. Because I tried row reduction on your two vectors, and(to my surprise) I get  $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&-1&1&1&-1\\ 0&1&-3&2&1&-3\end{bmatrix}.$$ This means that your original vectors were somehow carefully chosen so that you can span them with vectors with integer entries; that's just chance or choice, but not the general case by any means.

Comment: @Martin, OP writes "I know that all sets I will be applying this method to can be expressed this way," which I take to mean there is some theoretical reason why these vectors are guaranteed to have this property.

Comment: @Gerry, I missed that. I also noticed that there is an ambiguity in whether the requirement is for just two vectors, or more are allowed.

Comment: @Martin: to be clear, there can be any number of vectors in the set. Additionally, I know for a fact that the spanning set can be described with integers, and more specifically, with -1, 0, and 1. This is because holes are created with borders of single, individual simplices, which I explained in one of the comments above!